# Factory dependency in C++ classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Consider there are two classes, named `User` and `Player`. These classes, superficially, refer to users (accounts) in a game and players of them. Each user has one player, whereas each player could be owned by single user.

When user wants to join a game, a `Player` instance is created and the game abstraction will own the including players.

The instances of class `Player` should not be created by anyone other than a `User`. To be more precise, `User` has a method `Player *createPlayer(...)` in order to create a `Player`.

How this could be achieved? I considered `User` class could inherit from `Player`, so with a protected constructor of `Player` it will be okay. However, you know, this is ultimately odd. We would like to inherit `Player` from `User`, not the opposite.

Pseudocode of classes (as suggested by AndyG):

```
class User {
    String username
    String password

    func createPlayer(type: GameType, owner: Game) {
        var player = Player(type: type, owner: owner)

        return player
    }
}

class Player {
    private(set) Game owner
    private(set) GameType type
    Set<Weapon> loadout

    UInt kills
    UInt deaths

    init(type: GameType, owner: Game) {
        self.type = type
        self.owner = owner
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var user = User()    //  consider this gives you user
var game = Game()    //  consider there is a game

var player = user.createPlayer(.Deathmatch, game)    //  the way we should create it
var anotherPlayer = Player(.Deathmatch, game)        //  oops, compiler error.
```

Comment: Pseudocode or entity diagram?

Comment: @AndyG I didn't think it is necessary. I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make Player's constructor private, and Player declares User to be a friend. Then createPlayer can call Player's constructor normally, but no other class can. Try not to declare any other friends for Player, using friend is ok in certain situations but overuse is generally a bad sign.

Comment: Could you please add a C++ code block for it? I'm a newcomer to C++, actually I don't know what `friend` and `virtual` declerations exactly do. I just read that popular FAQ&FQA about C++.